# Microsoft SQL Server Differential Backup

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am creating differential backups of my database every 4h into one file. Today I wanted to restore to latest backup, but it doesn't work.

If I try to restore in SQL Management Studio, it doesn't recognize the full backup. When I browse back to Restore Point 81 (out of 150), it recognizes the full backup and is able to restore it. When I choose a point after 81, it is stuck in a loop.

I checked the headers of the backup file and found something odd.
All backups from 1-81 have the same DifferentialBaseLSN and DifferentialBaseGUID, after 81, it changed to a new LSN and GUI.

Is this the problem, why it doesn't recognize anything after 81? Can I change the LSN and GUID manually?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you restored the full backup, left it open and then tried to restore the diffs on top of that?

Comment: Yeah, I tried. It doesn't work for the most recent backup. Either it's stuck in a loop when trying to read the backup or it throws an error about no available data for a Rollforward.

Comment: DifferentialBaseLSN and DifferentialBaseGUID refer to the last full backup that each differential references (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188230(v=sql.105).aspx), and changes when a full backup occurs. So is it possible that a more recent full backup was taken at 81?

Comment: Thanks Xingzhou Liu!!! Thank you so much. I checked the backups and a coworker did a full backup manually. I was able to restore it now!

Comment: @Chixo [Copy-Only Backups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/copy-only-backups-sql-server)